# How to Select IRA Investments?

Tags: united-states, investing, retirement, ira

I'm helping a friend roll over his 401K into an IRA.  How can I advise him as he selects what to invest his money in?  Factors I know to consider:

- Rate of return over 1, 3, 5, and 10 years (and Morningstar rating, yes or no?)
- Expense ratio
- Risk factors such as R squared

I realize there are appropriate asset allocations for each stage between bonds and stocks, etc.  What else should my friend consider?

Comment: Morningstar Ratings might not be all their are cracked up to be (http://clarkhoward.com/liveweb/shownotes/2010/08/19/19103/)

Comment: @JohnFX - thanks.  By lowest cost do they mean lowest expense ratio?

Comment: In addition to the expense ratio, also consider the expense ratio, the expense ratio, and the expense ratio. Seriously. A difference of .5% means ~20% of your retirement fund after 40 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another aspect to consider is the proper asset allocation for his risk level. You shouldn't recommend your friend to be 100% in developing foriegn markets unless they're *really* risk tolerant (and even then, its probably not the best way to get good returns).

There are numerous [other posts about asset allocation as linked here.](https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=asset+allocation)

Comment: doh!  Didn't know to look under that tag.  A mod can close this question as a duplicate if there's another question that covers my concerns.  I do know allocation is important - Fidelity has all sorts of graphs they tout about it.