# Any Experience with the Gone Fishin' Portfolio?

Tags: united-states, retirement, ira, investing, asset-allocation

In doing research on [How to Select IRA Investments](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/how-to-select-ira-investments), I stumbled across the [Gone Fishin' Portfolio](http://www.gonefishinportfolio.com/).  [This link](http://www.investortrip.com/roth-ira/#54) where I found out about the portfolio claims that it is based on the 1990 economics Nobel Prize.  Is that a correct claim?

If you do know about the portfolio, do its claims appear to be true?  If you don't, would you consider trying it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes, the "based on" claim appears to be true** – but the Nobel laureate did not *personally* design that specific investment portfolio ;-)

It looks like the *Gone Fishin' Portfolio* is made up of **a selection of low-fee stock and bond index funds, diversified by geography and market-capitalization, and regularly rebalanced**.  Excerpt from [another article, dated 2003](http://www.investmentu.com/2003/September/20030905.html):

> **The Gone Fishin’ Portfolio**  [circa 2003]
>
> Vanguard Total Stock Market Index (VTSMX) – 15%
>   Vanguard Small-Cap Index (NAESX) – 15%
>   Vanguard European Stock Index (VEURX) – 10%
>   Vanguard Pacific Stock Index (VPACX) – 10%
>   Vanguard Emerging Markets Index (VEIEX) – 10%
>   Vanguard Short-term Bond Index (VFSTX) – 10%
>   Vanguard High-Yield Corporates Fund (VWEHX) – 10%
>   Vanguard Inflation-Protected Securities Fund (VIPSX) – 10%
>   Vanguard REIT Index (VGSIX) – 5%
>   Vanguard Precious Metals Fund (VGPMX) – 5%

That does appear to me to be an example of a portfolio based on [Modern Portfolio Theory (MPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_portfolio_theory), "which tries to maximize portfolio expected return for a given amount of portfolio risk" (per Wikipedia).  MPT was introduced by [Harry Markowitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Markowitz), who did go on to share the 1990 Nobel Memorial Prize in Economic Sciences.  (Note: That is the economics *equivalent* of the original Nobel Prize.)

You'll find more information at [NobelPrize.org - The Prize in Economics 1990 - Press Release](http://nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/economics/laureates/1990/press.html).

Finally, for what it's worth, it isn't rocket science to build a similar portfolio.  While I don't want to knock the *Gone Fishin' Portfolio* (I like most of its parts), there are many similar portfolios out there based on the same concepts.  For instance, I'm reminded of a similar (though simpler) portfolio called the *[Couch Potato Portfolio](http://www.moneysense.ca/2006/04/05/couch-potato-portfolio-how-to-set-it-up/)*, made popular by MoneySense magazine up here in Canada.

p.s. [This other question about asset allocation](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2284/what-is-the-best-asset-allocation-for-a-retirement-portfolio-and-why/2789#2789) is related and informative.

Comment: that's the sense I was getting, I just wanted to make sure the fundamentals were sound.  Ideally I'd like to learn the fundamentals and use them (rather than a specific set of Vanguard funds)

Comment: @justkt - the other question about asset allocation linked by Chris gives you exactly what you're looking for - a way to learn about the fundamentals of asset allocation. Look at the bottom of his post (I had the same question :-) )

Comment: I like this portfolio. However, I would like to caution naive investors about VGPMX. First, investing in this fund is not same as investing in gold. Second, this fund comprises of less than 50 mid-cap stocks cherry-picked by the manager, so you will be playing a very high-stakes game. Third, its actively managed and has a 33% turnover i.e., fund manager indulges in frequent buying and selling; the fund's composition changes quickly from year to year. Fourth, less than 60% of the fund is invested in gold mining companies; significant portion is in fertilizers.

Comment: @morpheus I agree that investing in gold and other mining companies is not strictly the same as investing in gold.  I prefer a small percentage position in an exchange-traded gold commodity, myself.  Its characteristics as a less-correlated hedge are preferable to gold company equity.